# Call custom Objective-C methods in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, function, methods, swift

I'm currently taking several Swift classes online to figure this new syntax out, but I feel like I've run into a wall that I can't really figure out.

My question is: What do I need to do to call custom Objective-C methods inside Swift? Why doesn't Swift recognize where the code is coming from? Why do I get errors like, "UIViewController does not have a member named 'customMethod'"? Is it an import problem?

Now that you know my question, here is why I'm asking and the background

I have an objective-c .m file that calls this method:

```
- (void)configureMyApp
{
// overridden by subclasses
}
```

Then this one:

```
- (void)addAppElement:(MyAppElement *)element
{
  [self addAppElement atIndex:[self.elements count]];
}
```

In my Swift app I've set up the bridging header and imported the .h file into said header file

I attempted calling the `configureMyApp` method through this Swift function:

```
func configureMyApp()
{

self.addAppElement...
}
```

but it doesn't recognize that function as coming from my imported objective-c file, and neither does myswiftfile.swift recognize `addAppElement`

The way I would call it in obj-c would be this:

```
- (void)configureMyApp
{
[super configureMyApp];

[self addAppElement:.....];
}
```

Is there anything else I need to do to import the obj-c code? What could I be missing?

Comment: Do you have your bridging header configured properly? See [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_76).

Comment: Did you added those methods to your ViewController.h file?

Comment: yes those methods are in my ViewController.h file, and I'm positive the bridging header is configured properly as I am already using a snippet of code that needs the bridging header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error: `UIViewController does not have a member named 'customMethod'` indicates that you're trying to call `customMethod` on an object typed as `UIViewController`, not as your custom subclass of `UIViewController`.

Comment: got it that did the trick! I forgot you needed to change the subclass